# pam_xauth isn't working with sudo: Unsupported authorisation protocol

Tags: ssh, x11, raspbian, pam

I'm trying to set up `xauth` cookie forwarding between users, so that GUI programs could be run as any user via SSH. I have added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/sudo`:

```
session    optional   pam_xauth.so
```

However, running GUI programs as `root` still fails:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xauth list
raspberrypi/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXX
raspberrypi/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXX
raspberrypi/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXX
raspberrypi/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXX
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ leafpad
# leafpad window opens

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# xauth list
xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# leafpad
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
leafpad: Cannot open display:

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# touch /root/.Xauthority
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# xauth add $(xauth -f ~pi/.Xauthority list | tail -1)
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# leafpad
# leafpad window opens
```

I don't have any `~/.xauth/import`/`~/.xauth/export` files for any of the users. I'm running PuTTY+Xming on the SSH client side (not that it should matter). I was expecting `pam_xauth` to create `/root/.Xauthority` for me, but that didn't happen. Any idea why?

Comment: And if you replace `sudo su` with `sudo -i` ?

Comment: @JiriB I get exactly the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that has changed since 2018, but now in 2021 on Debian Bullseye the config change described in the question works fine. `pam_xauth` [creates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676759/106927) a temporary file with the cookie and sets `$XAUTHORITY` to point to this file.

The problem is likely related to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/22) about `setuid()` call (set-user-ID). The version of `sudo` where it works is [1.9.4](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/SUDO_1_9_4/NEWS).