# Where is sudo hiding my root's .Xauthority data?

Tags: debian, sudo, xauth, pkexec

I just noticed something peculiar about how `sudo` handles the `.Xauthority` file:

```bash
sudo xauth add $(xauth list | tail -1)

user@server: sudo xauth info
Authority file:       /root/.xauthYZ21Nt
File new:             no
File locked:          no
Number of entries:    1
Changes honored:      yes
Changes made:         no
Current input:        (argv):1

user@server:  sudo xauth info
Authority file:       /root/.xauth3BFy5d
File new:             no
File locked:          no
Number of entries:    1
Changes honored:      yes
Changes made:         no
Current input:        (argv):1

user@server:  sudo xauth list
server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c922ab48defdf43b1092dffb86c06eed

user@server: sudo ls -la /root | grep auth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Nov  9 14:40 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 root root   57 Nov  9 15:23 .xauthsrxzxl

user@server:  pkexec xauth info
Authority file:       /root/.Xauthority
File new:             no
File locked:          no
Number of entries:    0
Changes honored:      yes
Changes made:         no
Current input:        (argv):1
```

So, `$XAUTHORITY` value is different in every new `sudo`, and it points to a temporary file which disappears when `sudo` quits. Because of this, the last command (which uses `pkexec` instead of `sudo` and expects it to be in `/root/.Xauthority`) fails to see the cookie. For instance, `sudo gedit` runs fine, but `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit` fails.

Why is it done in such a complicated way, where is the data stored, and more importantly, how can I access `.Xauthority` data with `pkexec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xauth cookie is stored in that temporary file (`~/.xauthXXXX`) which is removed when `sudo` returns (e.g. when the `sudo xauth info` command has finished).

I suggest you have a look at the source code of the [`pam_xauth`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_xauth/pam_xauth.c) module:

```
#define XAUTHTMP ".xauthXXXXXX"
...
int
pam_sm_open_session (pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags UNUSED,
                     int argc, const char **argv)
{
...

                /* Generate the environment variable
                 * "XAUTHORITY=<homedir>/filename". */
                if (asprintf(&xauthority, "%s=%s/%s",
                             XAUTHENV, tpwd->pw_dir, XAUTHTMP) < 0) {
...
                fd = mkstemp(xauthority + sizeof(XAUTHENV));
...
                cookiefile = strdup(xauthority + sizeof(XAUTHENV));

                /* Save the filename. */
                if (pam_set_data(pamh, DATANAME, cookiefile, cleanup) != PAM_SUCCESS) {
...
int
pam_sm_close_session (pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags UNUSED,
                      int argc, const char **argv)
{
...
        if (pam_get_data(pamh, DATANAME, &data) != PAM_SUCCESS)
                return PAM_SUCCESS;
        cookiefile = data;
...
        if (unlink(cookiefile) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
          pam_syslog(pamh, LOG_WARNING, "Couldn't remove `%s': %m", cookiefile);
```

---

As to `pkexec`, I don't think you're supposed to run X11 apps with `pkexec`. It's bad enough that you can run them with `sudo` ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Sure, the moment I will be able to run e.g. `gparted` using a GVfs admin scheme, I'll stop running it as `root`, but for now there is no other way AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

When an X server starts with `-auth` option it creates a file with `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` (password), and only users who know this password can display their windows in X window system.

There can be more then one `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` (net login, `ssh -X`, ...), but I think in your case, if you check these files - they will have the exact same content (`cmp /root/.xauth1 /root/.xauth2`).

However if you start a different X server, and use `sudo` (or `su`), the new password should be different.

So the reason for different files is because `sudo` didn't know which display is used by other instances and it gets the only passwords it needed (and creates new file to store it).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it's not stored anywhere between `sudo` calls.

Answer (score 1):

It all seems to be clear now, thanks @user499944. In short:

- the temporary `.xauthXXXXXX` files are created by `pam_xauth`.
- they are only created if `$DISPLAY` is set, which is the case with `sudo` but not with `pkexec`. Running `pkexed env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY command` achieves nothing, because `$DISPLAY` is only set **after** the authentication completes. This is revealed in the system logs:

```
# after pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY xauth info
Nov 11 18:01:41 server pkexec[11650]: pam_xauth(polkit-1:session): user has no DISPLAY, doing nothing
Nov 11 18:01:41 server pkexec[11650]: user: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=/dev/pts/3] [CWD=/home/user] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/env DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 xauth info]

# after sudo xauth info
Nov 11 18:04:12 server sudo[11666]: user : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/xauth info
# no message from pam_xauth about missing DISPLAY
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly workaround which allows `pkexec` to run correctly by copying the cookie twice:

```
sudo xauth -f /root/.Xauthority add $(xauth list $DISPLAY) # copy the cookie for pkexec

sudo gedit # works thanks to what sudo is doing
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit # works thanks to the first line above

# Check out that I now have two files
sudo ls -la /root | grep auth
-rw-------  1 root root   57 Nov 11 11:22 .xauth0XYhX3
-rw-------  1 root root   57 Nov 11 11:17 .Xauthority
```

I'm still looking for the answer to the original question (where the `xauth` data from the temporary files is actually stored?), which would hopefully allow me to use the same cookie for both `sudo` and `pkexec` commands.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part about *why* `pam_xauth` stores each cookie in a separate file, there are two reasons:

- to allow only that one display to be accessed, rather than all the user's current displays, and
- to allow that access to be removed at the end of the `sudo` session, by deleting the file.

In summary: scope and lifetime.